# How to automaticly provide constructors from generic base class in C#?

Tags: c#, class, constructor

So I have a generic base class like this:

```
class DatabaseDatasourceClassBase<DomainClass>
    where DomainClass : new()
{
    protected DomainClass m_DbObject;

    public AddableDatabaseDatasourceClassBase()
    {
        m_DbObject = new DomainClass();
    }

    public AddableDatabaseDatasourceClassBase(DomainClass initialObject, ISessionWrapper dbSession)
    {
        m_DbObject = initialObject;
        //Do stuff like calling SetSession(dbSession);
    }

    //Several functions and stuff like SetSession(ISessionWrapper dbSession)
}
```

I also got a lot (>20) of datasource-classes for the use in wpf-datagrids.

```
class CurrencyDatasource : AddableDatabaseDatasourceClassBase<Currency>
{
    //The constructors look always the same
    public CurrencyDatasource()
        :base()
    {
        
    }

    public CurrencyDatasource(Currency initialExchange, ISessionWrapper dbSession)
        :base(initialExchange, dbSession)
    {
    }

    
    //Following Properties are always different
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return m_DbObject.Name;
        }
        set
        {
            m_DbObject.Name = value;
        }
    }
}
```

So I wonder if there is a way to avoid having to write the same code (the 2 constructors + their call to the base class) in every Datasource class?

or

If this is not possible:

At least define that all classes which are derived from DatabaseDatasourceClassBase have to have these 2 Constructors?

Comment: Currently, there is no way to do this. I had proposed adding a feature to automatically extend base class's constructors ... https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/discussions/5732#discussioncomment-2135283

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So I wonder if there is a way to avoid having to write the same code (the 2 constructors + their call to the base class) in every Datasource class?

Each class must provide their own constructor(s) and define how they wish to call the base class's constructor(s).

> At least define that all classes which are derived from DatabaseDatasourceClassBase have to have these 2 Constructors?

Classes must call *at least one* base class constructor, but there is no way to enforce which one, or require more than one base constructor be hooked up.

---

That's at least in code.

I guess you could do something crazy with static code analysis.